# return statement in forEach won't stop execution of function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to determine whether or not an array holds a certain item. If it does, I would like to hold the function, otherwise it should get added.

```
function addPacking(item){

    data.packings.forEach(function(entry){
       if(item.name == entry.name){
           return;
       }
    });

    data.packings.push(item);

}
```

Unfortunately, the data is pushed even when the if condition is met. How do I prevent this behaviour without using an `else` condition?

(I do not want to use `else` because my actual code is a lot more complex than this and I'd like to keep it readable)

**Edit:**

Does `forEach` execute asynchronously?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Old ways are sometimes the best. It's because you're passing a delegate function when calling `.forEach`. The `return` within the delegate is getting lost, and isn't applying to anything. To get your desired result, you'll want to exit the calling function `addPacking`. This can be done using a simply `for` loop.

```
function addPacking(item){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.packings.length++; i++) {
        if (item.name == data.packings[i].name) {
            return;
        }
    }

    data.packings.push(item);
});
```

This approach also **supports older browsers**, unlike [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: It works but an array may also contains undefined (of course this may not be an issue for OP case).

Comment: That's correct Adriano, I'm just basing my conditions on those provided. :)

Comment: I found that this is the most convenient option, thank you and all others for providing so many different methods and explanations!

Comment: It worked. thank you :). We can also try this way 

** function addPacking(item){ 
       for (let record of data.packings) { 
             if (item.name == record.name) { return; } } data.packings.push(item); }); 

**

Comment: This is such a crazy error. I saw my code was executing in both "blocks" and remembered something about this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can't stop [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) execution other than throwing an exception (@Yoshi). Which should not be considered as an option to affect program code flow (@Me).

What you can do is to use another method `some` or `every`

```
function addPacking(item){
    var contains = data.packings.every(function(entry){
       return item.name != entry.name;
    });

    if(contains) {
       data.packings.push(item);
    }
}
```

Or

```
function addPacking(item){
    var conatins = !data.packings.some(function(entry){
       return item.name == entry.name;
    });

    if(contains) { 
       data.packings.push(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @epipav: The `forEach` method is a method, not the same as the `foreach` structure.

Comment: @epipav Wat?! "Note : There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop. The solution is to use Array.every or Array.some. See example below."

Comment: Using `every` or `some` will work, but the use of a side effect of the `&&` operator instead of an `if` statement doesn't make it very readable.

Comment: To be pedantic: *You can't stop forEach* is not true.

Comment: @Yoshi I doubt throwing exception should be considered by a pedantic programmer. :)

Comment: When not *exposed* to the caller, I don't see any real problem with that. ;)

Answer (score 3):

OLD question but in case someone else comes across this thread.

If you are using **ECMAScript 6** you can use the Array find() method

```
var found = myArray.find(function (element) { return element === arrayToFind; });
```

so for this particular scenario would be:

```
function addPacking(item){
    var foundItem = data.find(function(entry){ return entry.name == item.name});
    if (foundItem) data.packings.push(foundItem);    
}
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp for another worked example.

Answer (score 2):

Yo are just returning from the child function but not from the parent function

```
function addPacking(item){
    var check=false;
    data.packings.forEach(function(entry){
       if(item.name == entry.name){
          check=true; 
          return;
       }
    });
     if (check) return;
    data.packings.push(item);

}
```

Comment: That will work, but it will still loop through all the items even when a match is found, and the `return` inside the loop is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Return just aborts the function called in `forEach`, not your `addPackings` function.

```
function addPacking(item){
    var isInPackings = false;
    data.packings.forEach(function(entry){
       if(item.name == entry.name){
           isInPackings = true;
       }
    });
    if (!isInPackings)
        data.packings.push(item);

}
```